# Which one is correct sentence "The major revision ..."

Tags: american-english

Which one is more proper to native English people?

1. The major revision made by us is as follows:
2. The thing is edited on majority by us as following.

Comment: Option #2 does not make any sense to me. Option #1 appears to introduce the most impactful of multiple revisions made by a group of people represented by the speaker. To comment further, I’d need to know more about the situation. A/B or yes/no questions don’t tend to be a very good fit for the Stack Exchange format, so try to ask this in a way that makes it clear what it is you want to _understand_ as opposed to asking people to pick between options. You will need to share more of your thoughts about what’s going on with these words so that others can build on that understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our major revision was.....

The major revision (that) we made is as follows.

Comment: Hi tim,How about is this? " We made major revision is as follows"

Comment: `We made major revisions as follows...` or `We made a major revision as follows...`

Comment: Can't have  `We made.... is...`

Comment: Ok then how can I cut at this sentence ? "The major revision we made is as follows."? As I know, The major revision is noun. How can it put before subject(we)? I don't understand this sentence's structure.

Comment: Ah, now I see your confusion.  The subject is "revision".  The phrase "we made" is short for "that we made", and it is a clause that modifies "revision".  `The revision ... is as follows`.